# Plugin error "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap"

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ssis, dynamics-crm

I am using Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premises and SQL Server 2014 on 64-bit operation system Windows Server 2012 R2 on different machines.

I want to run a SSIS package from dynamics crm plugin dll.

The plugin code has references

[image]

I successfully registered the plugin as on-disk assembly and the step. I put `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll` into `crm\Server\bin\` and `crm\Server\bin\assembly\`.

I also registered it in the GAC.

But when the plugin step is running - I am getting the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

The 64-bit version of `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll` exists in `crm\Server\bin\` and `crm\Server\bin\assembly\`

Why can it not see the dll? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

With regards, Yuriy.